# choose cluster in hierarchical clustering

Tags: machine-learning, hierarchical-clustering

How can i choose a cluster if a point is at the same distance with two different points?
[image]

Here, `X1` is at the same distance to `X2` and `X3`. Can I directly make a cluster of `X1/X2/X3` or just go one by one as `X1/X2` and then `X1/X2/X3`?

Answer (score 0):

In general you should always follow the rule of merging two if you want to have all the typical properties of the hierarchical clustering (like uniform meaning of each "slice through" - if you start merging many steps into one, you will have "unbalanced" structure, thus the height of the clustering tree will have different meanings in multiple places). Furthermore, it actually only makes sense for min linkage, if you use avg linkage or other, more complex rules, then it is not even true then after merging two points, the third one will be the next now to add (it might even end up in a different cluster). However, in general, clustering of this type (greedy) is just a heuristic, with some particular properties. Thus alternating it a bit gives you yet another clustering with some properties. Saying which one is "correct" is impossible - they are both wrong to some extent, what matters is your exact usage later on.